# Debug Scala Project using Foreman

Tags: scala, debugging, scala-2.10, foreman

I have a Scala project and I'm using Foreman to run it on Linux. I haven't been able to debug it since my project doesn't use SBT files. I've seen other questions regarding Foreman debug but using Rails. Does anyone know if this can be accomplished?

**Note:** My Version of Scala is 2.10.4 and I'm using IntelliJ 14

Comment: You can debug Scala with appropriate JVM arguments over a socket just like java. I'm not sure where SBT comes into it. I don't know Foreman well enough to comment specifically, but if it allows passing an argument to the JVM then yes you can.